# Linq to Sql datacontext is not defined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

In the near future I am forced to work on the project visual basic web forms. I am a little confused.

***1st situation:***
**c# webform:**
When I add the `.aspx` file in the solution window I can extend file and there are `.aspx.cs` and `.aspx.designer.cs`
**Vb.net webform:**
When I add the `.aspx` file in the solution window I cant extend file. I can only press right mouse and select view code (`F7`).
Where are those files?
Where there are files in the solution?
if they are invisible how to do that were visible? **thx for Fabio'a answer**

***2nd situation:***
**c# webform:**
When I add the `.dbml` (linq to sql) file in the solution window I can extend file and there are `.dbml.layout` and `.aspx.designer.cs` When i want to refer a datacontext in codebehind the IDE suggest `filenameDataContext`. When i go to `.aspx.designer.cs` there is a huge generate class file.
**Vb.net webform:**
When I add the `.dbml` (linq to sql) file in the solution window I cant extend file When i want to refer a datacontext in codebehind the IDE dosent suggest `filenameDataContext`. When I press right mouse and select view code (`F7`) - IDE shows only:
    Partial Public Class WynikiDataContext
    End Class
How to generate a designer file and where i can find it?

**After fabio's answer** i see designer.vs. I have an error - `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`is not defined.`

```
Warning BC40056 Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Data.Linq' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.
```

How can I fix it?

I want to be more specific. This issue is driving me crazy. I'm not good in English so I decided to do a small show:

[Linq to sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R5Kc.jpg), 
[I lack words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nenhi.jpg), 
Dim db As New HelpMeDataContext - Type 'HelpMeDataContext' is not defined

What im doing wrong? When i do the same thing wiht c# webform its working

Comment: _Where are those files?_ - they exists in same way as in c# project. You need change options in Solution explorer to show all files. Pretty sure same options will work for second situation too

Comment: What a stupid question :) C # "show all files" is enabled in default. In vb isnt. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **c# webforms** i added dbml in App_Code folder - every is working
In **vba webforms** i added dbml in App_Code folder - and go an error `(Type 'HelpMeDataContext' is not defined bla bla bla)`
When i addned dbml in DIFRENT folder its working... i dont get it but it works